# Change android emojis for my app

Tags: android, ios, emoji

I am currently making a messenger app for android, and I just added emoticons. Now, I looked at the WhatsApp UI and I realized that they use the iOS emoticons for everything (even the ActionBar) and I was wondering how they had done this.

Is it possible to change Android's emoji texture atlas just for my app or something like that, and if so, where can I get these iOS emoticons and how do I implement that? Or do I have to write my own TextView / EditText / ... and my own emoji keyboard for it to look like WhatsApp's?

Thanks

Edit: I found out that there is an "Apple Color Emoji.ttf" without license that supports these emojis. Can I use this on android?

Comment: There must be a way but I am finding nothing except other people asking your same question with no reply

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out how to do it: I used the EmojiOne files instead of Apple's and a java encoded list of emojis from github and then replaced every emoji with a DrawableSpan in my EditText/TextView code